# Why is the meaning of Unanswered Question here different from its meaning on English Language and Usage?

Tags: discussion

When I click on "Unanswered Questions", I get a list of about 12 questions, which have **no** answers.  At ELU, "Unanswered Questions" means questions without an **accepted** answer.  Is the policy different here, and if so, why?

Comment: Good question-I've wondered about that too on the Gardening & Landscaping site!

Comment: @Sue Rory and Kevin between them answered the question for me. Are you satisfied too?

Comment: How sweet of you to ask! Yes, I am satisfied too. Rory and Kevin, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition on **all Stack Exchange sites** is exactly the same:

> questions with no upvoted or accepted answers

But each site remembers what subset of Unanswered you have selected.  Your options are **my tags**, **[newest](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)**, **[votes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)** and **no answers** so you have selected different options on each site.

As an example - as of right now, Outdoors has 45 questions "Unanswered" - 2 of these have 1 answer each, but that answer has no upvotes.

Comment: That helps, but does not solve my problem.  When I select "no answers"  I get 42 questions instead of 12, but a sampling of 10 of them have no (i.e., zero) answers.  Also, I asked a question some time ago, and did not accept an answer, and it is not in the list.http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/acclimitization-would-20-min-at-an-oxygen-bar-deliver-more-than-an-ephermal-b

Comment: Currently there are 45 "unanswered", including 2 with one answer that has no upvotes. Your question is on the list (on the 2nd page of them) and it has 1 answer.

Comment: I see a list of 42 questions, all of them with zero answers, all 42 on one page, starting with  http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/overview-of-free-and-open-huts-in-norway-outside-the-system-of-the-official-tour and ending with http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/how-to-plan-a-3d-archery-course.  I see no way to get to a second page.   Maybe I am blind, but I see no indication of a second page.

Comment: @ab2 it looks like you're on the "no answers" tab, which does not include questions with un-upvoted answers. Click [newest](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) or [votes](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. This solves my problem. I mistakenly thought that Unanswered on ELU meant Questions with No Accepted Answer; I did not realize it was "No Accepted Answer and No Answer with a Net Vote Greater than Zero". Sorry to have been careless in reading the descriptions.